# selenium2: clicking on a span: no error, but no effect, either

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Selenium 2.25, OSX ML, Firefox 14. ExtJS 4.1.1.

I have an 'itemclick' handler in an ExtJS tree panel.

Which is to say, I've got an item of xtype: 'treepanel', and a controller with a 'control' call including:

```
'#netree': {

                itemclick: this.neitemclick
            }
```

And it all works fine for real when clicked. Then I try to test it with Selenium.

In Selenium, I find the element for the span containing the text of an item, and I call `click()`. No errors finding the element, and no errors calling `click()`, but the handler does not run. Looking around, it looks as if Ext sets up the handler for the entire tree and then sees what you clicked on to decide what you meant. So clicking on the span down there should be effective.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you can post page source(with JS) it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Bmargulies,

Can you let us know which browser you are using?  Also if you can use Firefox and firefind the element using the same xpath/css that would be useful.

I would start by trying the click using the following, it should help determine the problem with the click.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) selenium).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementToClick);
```

or

```
JavascriptLibrary jsLib = new JavascriptLibrary(); 
jsLib.callEmbeddedSelenium(selenium,"triggerMouseEventAt", elementToClick,"click", "0,0");
```